# If the weak derivative $\nabla u$ of $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ exists, then $\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2=\int_\Omega|\nabla u^+|^2+\int_\Omega|\nabla u^-|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let

- $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded
- $u\in \mathcal{L}^2(\Omega)$ be *weakly differentiable*, i.e. $$\int_\Omega u\nabla\psi\;d\lambda^n=-\int\psi\nabla u\;d\lambda^n\;\;\;\text{for all }\psi\in C_0^\infty(\Omega)$$ (where we carefully denote the *weak derivative* of $u$ by $\nabla u$)
- $x^+:=\max(x,0)$ and $x^-:=\max(-x,0)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$

How can we show, that $$\int_\Omega\left|\nabla u\right|^2\;d\lambda^n=\int_\Omega\left|\nabla u^+\right|^2\;d\lambda^n+\int_\Omega\left|\nabla u^-\right|^2\;d\lambda^n\tag{1}$$ and what can we derive for $\nabla u^\pm$? (e.g. $\nabla u^\pm=\nabla u$ almost everywhere in $\left\{u^\pm >0\right\}$ or even $\nabla u=\nabla u^+-\nabla u^-$ almost everywhere).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think theorem 4 (iii) on page 131 in [this](https://books.google.com/books/about/Measure_Theory_and_Fine_Properties_of_Fu.html?id=HZONacVPGlMC&hl=en) book is good enough to answer your question.